# I'm trying to fetch rows based on the "created_at" field that are older than (for example) 30 days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to fetch rows based on the `created_at` field that are older than (for example) 30 days.

I'm using Laravel Eloquent. Can somebody help me with this?

I want to change the text in crud to be red  here is my code

```
public function   get_list_credit(Request $request)
{

    $resultat=tbl_depot::whereEtatservi('Etatservi'== 0) 
               ->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(); 

   if('created_at' >= Carbon::now()){
   
   }else{

   }
    return response()->json(['data'=>$resultat ]);
}
```

Comment: Put that into a whereDate https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses Note: SO is not a replacement for looking at the manual

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`whereDate()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate) and `Carbon` [`subDays()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) to achieve this:

```php
$result = tbl_depot::whereDate('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(30))->get();
```

Comment: hi there could you help me to check it if the created_at is has reach one month

Comment: and change the color to red in datatable

Comment: here my code public function   get_list_credit(Request $request)
        {     
                  $resultat=tbl_depot::whereEtatservi('Etatservi'== 0) 
                            ->whereDate('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(30))
                           ->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(); 
                           if('created_at' < now()->subDays(30)){
                               $color='green';
                           }

                  return response()->json(['data'=>$resultat]);

        }

Comment: @Devzoo I suggest you open a new question for that and include what you have tried and the problems you're having.